# Ruby: String#strip which whitespace characters?

Tags: ruby, whitespace, strip

Which whitespace characters do the [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html) methods `lstrip`, `lstrip!`, `rstrip`, `rstrip!`, `strip`, `strip!` remove?

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal/vertical tabs, newlines, page/form feeds, carriage returns, and spaces.

For ASCII strings, the `strip` methods use the String class's `ascii_isspace` method, which looks up the character in `isspacetable`. [This table identifies character codes 9-13 and 32 as whitespace.](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/string.c#5894).